# Php code on How to check if a value appears many times in an array and display each value and how many times they appear without repeating it

Tags: php, mysql

I want to write a PHP code that can sort through an array of list of registered emails from the database. Then check when a value appear a second time and in stead of displaying it multiple times, it will add the number of times that value has in the array.

This is what I am doing but it didn't work out what I want.

```
    function select_names(){
         $names=array(John,
                      Mark,
                   Phillip,
                  Blessing,
                   Victory,
                      John,
                      Mark,
                   Phillip,
                  Blessing,
                  Victory);
        foreach($names as $name){
            for($i=0; $i<count($names); $i++){
                if($name !==$names[$i]){
                   echo $name."<br/>";   
                }
            }
        }
    }

select_names()
?>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check my below code to know how to count a value appears how many times.

```
<?php

function select_names()
{

    $names = array(
        'John',
        'Mark',
        'Phillip',
        'Blessing',
        'Victory',
        'John',
        'Mark',
        'Phillip',
        'Blessing',
        'Victory'
    );

    $result = [];
    foreach ($names as $name)
    {
        if (isset($result[$name]))
        {
            $result[$name]++;
        }
        else
        {
            $result[$name] = 1;
        }
    }

    foreach ($result as $name => $count)
    {
        echo "{$name}: {$count}" . "<br/>";
    }

}

select_names();

?>
```

Comment: I checked this and it works, Thanks so much